# Ionic - Cannot load empty config.xml file

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

I am getting a Cannot load empty config.xml file when I try to run ionic cordova run android.  Has anyone ever encountered this problem before?  ionic serve seems to work.

[image]

Comment: check your config.xml whether it is empty or not as well as check whether you have added the android or ios platform

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This error is because your global config.xml file is empty for some reason.
You should check config.xml file of your Ionic project, it's located in /your/project/path/config.xml and recover its last content.

Comment: This was the problem.  Thanks

Comment: My config.xml has seemingly been randomly going blank.  Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Do you use git in your project ?

Comment: If you use Git, you can use it to recover config.xml content.

Comment: Right, thats exactly what I did but I am still perplexed as to why it went blank in the first place - I certainly did not do that

Comment: It happened randomly for me as well. I had to use git to revert the content of that file...nice.

Comment: I've got the same issue, each time I stop `ionic cordova run android -l -c --device` using ctrl+break (may reproduce with other commands)

Answer (score 32):

Just use the below command it will work!

ionic integrations enable cordova --add

Comment: This can cause another issue just copy your .code back if you have pushed it to github before.

Comment: true, I realized it later, it would be generated angular imports in ionic with umd, therefore be careful, If you cannot restore from git better to got with above solution and delete umd  from imports in ts files.

Answer (score 8):

```
ionic integrations enable cordova --add
```

This solution worked for me. But as I read other posted solutions. I recommend you not to overwrite the `resource` folder
Do overwrite `config.xml` folder (because in my case this is root of issues).

Thanks and Love

Answer (score 0):

I went to github copied the codes inside my config.xml on my previous push to github, paste it on my local config.xml and walahi it worked.
Try this.

Answer (score 0):

I also got into the same problem.
Just delete the config.xml file and run this command to create a new one

```
ionic integrations enable cordova --add
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

That file might get randomly deleted, So take that file back,Working for me fine